# Estimator of moments

Tags: self-study, estimation

If $X_1,..,X_n$ is a random sample with density $f(x;\theta)=e^{-(x-\theta)}e^{-e^{-(x-\theta)}}$ ($x \in\mathbb{R}$) and $-\infty<\theta<\infty$,

$\quad$i) Find the estimator of $\theta$ through method of moments
$\quad$ii) Find the maximum likelihood estimator of $\theta$

The problem to find the estimator by the method of moments is to calculate the expectation:

$$E[X]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xe^{-(x-\theta)}e^{-e^{-(x-\theta)}}dx$$

I am not able to calculate that expectation.

Comment: Your $f$ cannot possibly be a density, because it is obviously negative whenever $x$ is negative.  Please recopy your question correctly.

Comment: @whuber now it's right

Comment: I'm afraid it's not right--your edit has not fixed the problem. Presumably by now you have carefully checked the original question, so that means it must be erroneous.  You will need to go back to the author of the question to learn what they really intended.

Comment: @whuber The problem is that this exercise is a homework, and do not know where it was taken, but the statement is exactly that.

Comment: Then the only possible correct answer is that the question is nonsense, because $f$ does not define a distribution.

Comment: @whuber I am losing you here - this is the density of the Gumbel distribution. What am I missing?

Comment: @askazy Try the transformation $$z = e^{-(x-\theta)}$$

Comment: @Alecos The problem was subtle: due to missing punctuation, the OP originally wrote that the distribution was $x$ times a Gumbel. I eventually figured that out and inserted parentheses in an edit made from my phone.  It's hard to write comments from a phone so I didn't bother to explain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer first part:

First let's confirm if  $f(x;\theta)=e^{-(x-\theta)}e^{-e^{-(x-\theta)}}$ represents a PDF.

Transforming $t=e^{-({x-\theta})}$:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} e^{-(x-\theta)}e^{-e^{-(x-\theta)}}dx  = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-t} dt = 1$$

This is indeed a [known distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution)

Now, using similar transformation($t=e^{-(x-\theta)}$) for $$E[X]=\int_{-\infty}^\infty xe^{-(x-\theta)}e^{-e^{-(x-\theta)}}dx$$

we get

$$E[X]=\int_{0}^\infty (\theta-ln (t))e^{-t}dt$$

$$E[X]=\theta - \int_{0}^\infty  ln (t)\ e^{-t}dt$$

Thus, 
$$ E[X] = \theta + \gamma$$

where the second term is [Euler Mascheroni constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%E2%80%93Mascheroni_constant) $\gamma$

Comment: This is a "self-study" question. While your resolution is correct,providing the straight answer does not help the OP to solve the problem by himself.